# Most versatile font for printing and screen?

Tags: css, printing, fonts

I have to choose a font for a web application that produces a printable view of some text (long text, no colors, white background).

Example [here](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/export?question=3244901&format=HTML&service=stackoverflow&printer=false).

Users will read this printable view in these possible ways:

1. From pc\Ereader (after saving it in html)
2. From pc\Ereader (after "printing" it in Pdf, mac users will natively do it)
3. From paper

Temporarily i have chosen the web workhorse Georgia font for the screen reading, and although my css has a `@media print` directive, i have not yet redefined any different print font.
In few words, i don't know if i should differentiate the printing font from the one for screen;
changing the `@media print` font will affect also the 2.pc\Ereader users that like to read their Pdf on screen.

So i'm searching for a font that should satisfy these requirements:
1. Should have a good compromise in term of readibility\legibility for printing and screen reading
2 (bonus). Should handle strange unicode characters (Georgia is missing something [here](http://stackprinter.appspot.com/export?question=52671&format=HTML&service=superuser&printer=false))

Any hints?
Any better approach?

Comment: Wingdings?  I think it's equally legible on screen or in print, and it definitely handles strange characters.

Comment: @systempuntoout: oh no!  It was a joke!  Forgive me!

Comment: @Borealid yep, i've tried it with firebugs and looks orrible :)))

Comment: @Borealid: I though April, 1st was already over? ;-)

Comment: Do you mind explaining the downvote? thanks

Comment: @systempuntoout - Yeah that irks me too. For the record, I +1ed it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally when reading long passages of text, you want to use a serif font. It leads the eyes easier, which makes reading that little bit less stressful on your eyes/brain. Personally I like Garamond, Goudy, and some of the Century fonts.

If you need to use a sans-serif font, might I suggest Univers? it's like the cooler older brother of Helvetica.

If you can ONLY use web-safe fonts, you're probably best going with Times or Helvetica. (Or you could do some font-importing)

Also make sure to take care with your line-height (leading, in ye olde printing terms) as text that is too spaced or too cramped makes for harder reading. Generally sans-serif fonts require more leading to help guide the eye along.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried Helvetica?

There is a bit of a cult following for this, more info at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica_(film)

Particularly interesting is the 'Useage' section on the first link

The font is widely used for print and screen purposes across the world, so might be worth a try.

Comment: I find Helvetica tiring for long passages of text. Awesome for short passages of text though. It _is_ very resilient under a wide array of output resolutions.

Comment: @sarnold what do you think about Georgia?

Comment: @systempuntoout, if your example link correctly rendered Georgia in my Firefox, I liked it.